# What does zero-indexed mean in context of axis in numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I was studying concatenation of numpy arrays, where I encountered this code snippet:

```
# concatenate along the second axis (zero-indexed)
np.concatenate([grid, grid], axis=1)
```

What does the term zero-indexed mean in this context?

Maybe this screenshot may help you understand my problem:

[image]

Comment: The `axis` of an array are numbered 0,1, ....  That's same as all of Python's (and `numpy) indexing.  In those examples, one concatenates on the default axis 0, resulting in vertical stacking, the other does horizontal stacking (axis=1).

Comment: A 3D array has axes `0, 1, 2`

Comment: Don't just read the docs (that's good), but also start an interactive session (best use `ipython`), and experiment.  Try simple things yourself.  It's like learning a new language - practice, don't just read.

Comment: Yeah, sure! I know that for vertical stacking, the value of the parameter axis is 0, and for the horizontal stacking, it is 1. Then, why zero-indexed is mentioned near the second axis, what does that mean, in the code snippet provided, that's basically confusing me!

Answer (score 1):

Python uses zero-based indexing. That means, the first element(value 'red') has an index 0, the second(value 'green') has index 1, and so on.
Since you are concatenating its relevant as the array starts with 0 index